# Sum of squares of length of longest common prefix for all pairs in given strings

Tags: data-structures, strings

Given a list of unique strings, how can I find the sum of squares of longest common prefixes length for all pairs?
I think a trie will be useful but I'm not sure how to calculate the final result.

For example, if given strings are **and**, **anacron**, **anagram**, **build** and **buffer**

Then possible pairs are (and, anagram) which will give 2 as the length of common prefix and squaring it we will get **4**
similarly, for (anagram, anacron) we will get 3 common prefixes and we will add **9** and (and, anacron) will give **4**, (build, buffer) will give **2**
Other possible pairs will have 0 common prefixes hence they do not contribute.
So the final answer will be 4+9+4+4 = 21.

I assume adding the length of squares and not the original length is a key to calculate the result.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are interested in going over all unordered pairs of distinct words in your given set of words $S$, a collection I denote by $S_2$.

You can augment a trie for $S$ with a count of the words extending each node. Suppose that a node $v$ corresponds to a prefix of length $|v|$, and has $n(v)$ words extending it. Using $v \preceq x$ to denote "$v$ is a prefix of $x$" and $c(x,y)$ to denote the size of the largest common prefix of $x,y$, for any function $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
\sum_v f(|v|) \binom{n(v)}{2} = \sum_v \sum_{\substack{\{x,y\} \in S_2 \\ v \preceq x,y}} f(|v|) = \sum_{\{x,y\} \in S_2} \sum_{v \preceq x,y} f(|v|) = \sum_{\{x,y\} \in S_2} \sum_{\ell=0}^{c(x,y)} f(\ell).
$$
In your case, you are interested in finding a function $f$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
\sum_{\ell=0}^n f(\ell) = n^2.
$$
Clearly $f(0) = 0$ and for $\ell > 0$, $f(\ell) = \ell^2 - (\ell-1)^2 = 2\ell-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation, but can you provide with an algorithm or maybe some form of code to support the above explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Unfortunately the mathematical explanation is not of that much use for me. A pseudocode for the same would have been much appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming site.